# Which File Did Microsoft Safety Scanner Fix?

Tags: virus, malware, spyware, security

Microsoft Safety Scanner says it partially fixed a file.  How do I find out which file it fixed?

Comment: Is there anything in the system or application event log

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Safety Scanner apparently saves a log file of everything it does. Opening it up in Notepad should let you see what it did and to what file.

The log file is located at `%SystemRoot%\debug\msert.log`.

Comment: Does this tool automatically removes the files without asking for user permissions?

Comment: EDIT: I just ran it the first time today. A full scan. It automatically removed a virus (Trojan:Win32/Tiggre!plock) without asking for my permission. It says this in the results Windows window. The "msert.log" log file does not show that it removed this trojan or from what file it did it to: "Results Summary: No infection found."

Comment: I posted details of it here: https://superuser.com/questions/1815491/what-file-did-microsoft-safety-scanner-removed-a-virus-from-if-any