# What file did Microsoft Safety Scanner removed a virus from? If any?

Tags: security, anti-virus, microsoft-safety-scanner, safety-scanner

Microsoft Safety Scanner *seems* to be contradictory:

I ran Microsoft Safety Scanner, it showed a trojan was deleted, it did not say from what file, and its log says no infection was found.

What is happening here?

Details:

After the scan:

[image]

The results:

[image]

The log file (C:\Windows\debug\msert.log):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft Safety Scanner v1.401, (build 1.401.143.0)
Started On Sun Nov  5 18:17:39 2023

Engine: 1.1.23100.2009
Signatures: 1.401.143.0
MpGear: 1.1.16330.1
Run Mode: Interactive Graphical Mode

Results Summary:
----------------
No infection found.
Successfully Submitted Heartbeat Report
Microsoft Safety Scanner Finished On Sun Nov  5 18:21:31 2023


Return code: 0 (0x0)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft Safety Scanner v1.401, (build 1.401.143.0)
Started On Sun Nov  5 18:29:16 2023

Engine: 1.1.23100.2009
Signatures: 1.401.143.0
MpGear: 1.1.16330.1
Run Mode: Interactive Graphical Mode
```

Notice it says no infection.

(P.S. I found out about the log file from this similar question:
[Which File Did Microsoft Safety Scanner Fix?](https://superuser.com/questions/291069/which-file-did-microsoft-safety-scanner-fix))

Comment: Safety Scanner is not Windows Defender. Open WD and see if the file has been Quarantined.

Comment: Thanks, that's where the information was! And it was a faulty positive, unfortunately, I did not want it to remove this "trojan."

Comment: @Xonatron - Submit a detailed answer

Comment: Done. Thank you both!

Comment: I looked up Safety Scanner and got a Microsoft Learn article. It is a standalone App and not an AV suite. Better off just to stick with Windows Defender

Comment: Agreeing with you. Full story: Google wanted me to reset my password, indicating an unwanted app (virus?) may be abusing it. When Windows Defender could not find a potential virus (app) I wanted to did deeper and used Safety Scanner. Not sure if this was the right thing to do, but perhaps it's more thorough.

Answer (score 1):

(As https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john mentioned in the comments above...)

Safety Scanner is not Windows Defender, and it may be Windows Defender with the details I seek.

I looked into Windows Defender history and found the details I wanted!

[image]

More details:

The file that was (not) affected which is interesting to my unique circumstance of Safety Scanner claiming it removed a trojan but its log showing no infection and no action.

Windows Defender was not able to quarantine it. Not sure why.

(Lastly, the file was a false positive from an old-school game that has been on my computer for decades. In case it matters.)

Comment: Let me know how I should be tagging users for credit.